# How to set pixel values of a matrix at specific indexes to pixel values of a different matrix with the same indexes?

Tags: matlab, matrix, image-thresholding

What I'm trying to do is image thresholding with matrix operations, but rather than setting the threshold result equal to a fixed value, like 256 or something, I'm trying to set the result equal to the calculation of pixel values from two other images of the same size. So, for example:

```
firstImage = img1;
secondImage = img2;
thirdImage = img3;
secondImage(firstImage < 100) = thirdImage(at the same indexes as where the thresholding condition holds true) .* 10;
```

MATLAB normally attempts to multiply the entire `thirdImage .* 10` and save that, but what I want is only those specific pixels that match to do the operation and overwrite the respective values in the `secondImage`.

How to do this?

Comment: You have answered it yourself in the question:    `secondImage(firstImage<100)=thirdImage(firstImage<100)*10;`

Comment: @SardarUsama Thank you! If you want to write that as a full comment, I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have kinda figured it out yourself in the question:

```
secondImage(firstImage < 100) = thirdImage(firstImage < 100) * 10;
```

i.e. just like you're indexing `secondImage`, index `thirdimage` in the same way.